# How can i dynamically "fill" a Layout with already existing objects in PyQt5?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5

I have a ScrollArea with a Grid Layout inside of it.

Inside that grid layout, i am initially creating a lot of checkboxes inside that grid Layout.

Now when i use `.hide()` on a checkbox, the white space persists. Only when i hide all checkboxes within a row, the row is hidden.

How can i ensure that when i hide some checkboxes, the checkboxes below "move up" to fill the space? I already used `.update()` on the parent widget. I cant provide a code example but i assume this is a pretty basic UI operation so i hope someone knows what i am talking about. I tried fiddling around with the sizePolicy but didnt find the solution sadly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. Imagine a grid layout as a table of a spreadsheet: if you delete a cell, the spreadsheet will not move the following cells, and even if it would, what should it do? Move cells of the following the row? Why not those of the following column? If you want to "move" widgets in a grid, you have to do it programmatically, by calling `addWidget` again with the new row and column.

Comment: I have the same issue, but in my case removing and adding it again would make it a whole lot more complicated - perhaps there is a method to move an object without removing/adding it...